# PyQGIS, features geometry type changes to unknown after copying to another layer

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I'm copying a subset of features from a shapefile based QgsVectorLayer (polyline type shapefile) to a memory based QgsVectorLayer('LineString', layername ,'memory'):

```
self.lyr_flightlines_selected.startEditing()

selected = []
for f in self.lyr_flightlines.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(u'"id"={}'.format(selected_id))):
                feat = QgsFeature()
                feat.setGeometry(f.geometry())
                feat.setAttributes(f.attributes())
                selected.append(feat)

                print f.geometry().type(), feat.geometry().type()


self.lyr_flightlines_selected.dataProvider().addFeatures(selected)
self.lyr_flightlines_selected.commitChanges()
```

Selected layer features are presented on the map  without a problem, I can also access attributes of features I copied into the selection layer. But if I try to  access the geometry I get an  instance of QgsGeometry, but its type() returns unknown geometry. And if I print for example feat.geometry().asPolyline() I get an  empty list. I don't know why, because the features are visible on map?! hence they have to have valid geometry. What am I missing here?

(Using QGIS 2.8.2)